# React Native - How to change bubble style

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm trying to change the background color of the chat bubble from react native.

It seemed so simple here: https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-chat/issues/493

And that's exactly the code I added, but then I got

```
You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.
Check the render method of `Message`.
```

Which lead me to try a bunch of different things that didn't work. And I know it must be super simple, but I know next to nothing about React Native :/

Do you know why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Can you show us the code for your `Message` component?

Comment: @Dan I'm entering the project now, so I'm unfamiliar with the code, but it must be a pre-made component, because there's no file with that name. Looking around the code I also can't find anything with "Message" component

Comment: It's not one of the framework components so they're probably pulling it from a third party library somewhere if its not defined explicitly in your project. Check your dependencies and then the documentation associated with it.

Comment: @nordicnomad oh ok, thank you! I though it was a normal react native thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have imported Bubble?

```
import { GiftedChat, Bubble } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
```

Do you have set your renderBubble function as props of GiftedChat as below?

```
<GiftedChat
            messages={this.state.messages}
            onSend={this.onSend}
            renderBubble={this.renderBubble}
            user={this.state.currentUser}
            showUserAvatar={true}
 />
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to display different color for two users this will work. It also accepts other text styles.

```
import { GiftedChat, Bubble, Time} from 'react-native-gifted-chat';


 <GiftedChat
    messages={messages}
    onSend={newMessage => onSend(newMessage)}
    renderBubble={props => {
      return (
        <Bubble
          {...props}

          textStyle={{
            right: {
              color: 'white',
              fontFamily: "CerebriSans-Book"
            },
            left: {
              color: '#24204F',
              fontFamily: "CerebriSans-Book"
            },
          }}
          wrapperStyle={{
            left: {
              backgroundColor: '#E6F5F3',
            },
            right: {
              backgroundColor: "#3A13C3",
            },
          }}
        />
      );
    }}                
    user={{
        _id: 1,
    }}
/>
```